# Wordpress PHP email script

Tags: php, wordpress, email, plugins

I am working on a project at the moment in wordpress and I need a php script that sends an email to the admin (me) when a user clicks on a button (that redirects to the script) I was hoping the email could send the following data to the admin:

1. username
2. the post or URL in which this user was on when they clicked on the button

I have been looking for a plugin for hours and have searched for script everywhere, I'm not exactly the best coder and appreciate the help.

Comment: Do you have any php at all? What are you putting this in? You don't need a plugin, you just need to learn to use `wp_mail()`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply cale.

I don't have a plugin, what would be the best way to go about learning to use wp_mail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a PHP snippet that should send you the page and the information about the user.

You may need to install the Wordpress PHP addon to insert this code.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-php/

```
<?php

    $email_body = '';

    // Get the previous post
    $previous_page = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    $email_body .= 'Post or URL: ' . $previous_page . '<br />';

    // Get the user information
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $email_body .= 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . '<br />';
    $email_body .= 'User email: ' . $current_user->user_email . '<br />';
    $email_body .= 'User first name: ' . $current_user->user_firstname . '<br />';
    $email_body .= 'User last name: ' . $current_user->user_lastname . '<br />';
    $email_body .= 'User display name: ' . $current_user->display_name . '<br />';
    $email_body .= 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID . '<br />';

    // Send email
    $to = 'you@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Button was clicked';
    $message = $email_body;
    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message);

?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much mark! I'll try it out and see how I go.

Much apprreciated!

Comment: No problem, if you use the addon, you have to use "[insert_php]" instead of "<?php" on the first line and "[/insert_php]" instead of "?>" on the last line.

Comment: would I also be able to create a .php file and link to this script from a button? I would have no idea how to make it activate via a click otherwise.

Cheers again!

Comment: I'm not sure if you'll still have access to the word press variables like the $user if you're not running this through a Wordpress page.

Comment: If that's the case I can probably just create a landing page for the php script and link to that from the button!

Comment: Yea I think that should do it, as long as its a wordpress page

Comment: worked perfectly and does exactly what I need it to do you're an absolute legend!

Comment: If you click the grey tick under the up and down vote, you accept the answer as the correct one and you help both of our reputation :)